# DECIMAL Types in tsql

Tags: t-sql, byte, decimal, storage

I have a Table with about 200Mio Rows and multiple Columns of Datatype DECIMAL(p,s) with varying precision/scales.
Now, as far as i understand, DECIMAL(p,s) is a fixed size column, with a size depending on the precision, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Now, when altering the table and changing a column from DECIMAL(15,2) to DECIMAL(19,6), for example, i would have expected there to be almost no work to be done on the side of the SQL-Sever as the required bytes to store the value are the same, yet the altering itself does take a long time - so what exactly does the server do when i execute the alter statement?

Also, is there any benefit (other than having constraints on a column) to storing a DECIMAL(15,2) instead of, for example, a DECIMAL(19,2)? It seems to me the storage requirements would be the same, but i could store larger values in the latter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision and scale of a decimal / numeric type matters considerably.

As far as SQL Server is concerned, decimal(15,2) is a *different* data type to decimal(19,6), and is *stored* differently. You therefore cannot make the assumption that just because the overall storage requirements do not change, nothing else does.

SQL Server stores decimal data types in byte-reversed (little endian) format with the *scale* being the first incrementing value therefore changing the definition can require the data to be re-written, SQL Server will use an internal worktable to safely convert the data and update the values on every page.

Comment: Ah i see my mistake, thanks alot! guess my approach was a bit like saying an integer and a char(4) have the same storage requirements therefore they should be equal, which is obviously false - thanks for that!

Is there any way to see exactly how the value is stored on sql server? 
Also, my other question - is there any disadvantage of storing a DECIMAL(19,2) instead of a DECIMAL(15,2) then?

Comment: As you note the storage requirements are the same but that's not the only concern, there may be other dependancies such as data validation requirments, just because you can doesn't *necessarily* mean it should be allowed, ymmv.